# Maple: simplification expression with some assumption

Tags: maple

I need to to some transformation of expression.
I have W:=a*x+b*y+c*z. Now I want to set a*x=0.5*x, b*y=-0.5*x. After that I need to get W.
Can I do it using Maple?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to handle your example,

```
W := a*x+b*y+c*z:

eval(W, [a*x=0.5*x, b*y=-0.5*x]);

       c z

simplify(W, [a*x=0.5*x, b*y=-0.5*x]);

       c z
```

Note that your syntax is unclear. I can't tell whether you have the names `ax` and `by` or the products `a*x` and `b*y`.